# Deploy a project in tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat6

I'm trying to deploy a war file onto my server which is tomcat 6 and it runs on a linux machine. My project runs if i give the url with the port number eg: http://192.168.1.8:8080/uctc but it fails to run if i run it without the port number eg ://192.168.1.8/uctc ...can anyone tell me how to run my website without the port number??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8080 is default tomcat port, so configure your tomcat server to use 80 port other than 8080.
see: http://www.klawitter.de/tomcat80.html

Answer (score 0):

Check in server.xml... there is an entry similar to Connector port="8080".. change the 8080 to just 80 and save. Then restart the tomcat service

This is assuming you're not already running another service on port 80 .

Comment: actualy i dont want to mention the port number eg: http://192.168.1.8/uctc instead of http://192.168.1.8:8080/uctc is it possible??

Comment: using http assumes port 80 by default so you shouldn't have to specify the port in this case.  http://192.168.1.8/uctc should work fine after this change

Comment: but one of my projects deployed in the same webapps folder runs without the port no. why am i facing this problem with the project

Comment: resolved it spoke to my sysadmin he told me we have to make a n entry in /etc/httpd/conf.d/prox_ajp.conf a proxy pass for each module in the webapps folder. thanks for the replies !!